# Problem applying textures

Tags: texturing, materials

I have problem rendering my textures. I am doing tutorial on tunnels.
[image]

In the first image the tunnel has a nice round shape, but textures on the upper half are getting messy. I tried to fix it and change shading of the wall to smooth.
[image]

That changed the image a little bit, and cleaned up the texture issues. However the tunnel seems to have lost its round shape at the same height as the texture issue was located, and gets messed up behind the pipes on the left.

Comment: kila11: you can upload .blend file to PasteAll.org.  You can copy the URL after the file uploads and paste it here.  Your Google Drive account requires permission to access.

Comment: I almost forgot, you should also upload the images either by packing them in the .blend or by uploading them separately.  You can also limit the uploaded .blend size by only including a small segment of the hallway and also remove any subdivision modifiers and unnecessary textures.  You can leave those pipes and lights out as well.

Comment: Thanks for Your advices. Next time if i ask any question i will do as You said. I think main reason i had problem with this texture, is that i am dumb and didn't follow tutorial to the letter. I haven't applied array modifier to the wall. After applying modifier and adding yours suggestion, tunnel looks pretty neat. Thanks and apologies.